# autocompletado desde una base de datos

Tags: autocompletar

buenas espero por favor alguno pueda ayudarme, quiero hacer un autocompletado desde una base de datos mysql, por alguna razon si trato de seleccionar una de las opciones del autocompletado no me deja[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, no añadas codigo como imagen te invito a checar lo siguiente [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) tambien indica en las etiquetas que lenguaje o tecnolgia estas usando, saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [autocompletado desde una base de datos en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/493405/autocompletado-desde-una-base-de-datos-en-java) || Marcada como duplicada, porque en realidad la otra pregunta es una ampliación y mejora de esta.